# What difference does the parameter "bw" makes in the kdeplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have tried plotting a bivariate KDE-Plot using seaborn using different values for parameter "Bw" so as to understand the interplay between my variables better.

I can't figure out how the scale changes when we vary "bw" from 0.5 to 0.75 to 1.5 and what difference does it make to our understanding of the bi-variate density plot.

```
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(15.7, 8.27)
ax = sns.kdeplot(df_reqd_data_0['Customer_Age'], df_reqd_data_0['Policies'],
                 cmap="Reds", shade=False, bw=.5, cbar=True)
ax.set(xlabel='Customer_Age', ylabel='Policies')
plt.show()
```

[Image of plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gIQ4.png)

Comment: Checkout the theory of [kernel-density estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation). You might call it the *smoothing parameter*. Wiki even contains a demo-pic exactly showing that this param does.

Comment: Thank you @sascha. It was really useful.